# RotateAnimation Get Current angle of image

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I have a question of RotationAnimation.

First.
Is there a Listener to during animation?
start, start animation
repeat, repeat animation
stop, stop animation.

but there are no animation listener to check the on going.

second,
is any other get a current rotate angle of image?

I think, ImageView is rotate by rotationAnimation function.
so I made a timer thread and run 1second

```
'''
timer = new Timer();
       timerTask = new TimerTask() {
       public void run(){
       Log.e("LOG",  " [angle]: " + String.format("%3.1f",  rotateImage.getRotation());
    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);

'''
```

but, I can't see the changed value during rotate.

how can I get the current angle during rotate?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Rotation Animation, Yes There is as shown below:

```js
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation();
rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

  }
});
```

You can also use Object Animators to animate Rotation:

```js
ObjectAnimator rotateAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, View.ROTATION, startAngle, endAngle);
rotateAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

  }
});
```

To get the angle of your ImageView simply use `imageView.getRotation();` this will give you an `int` value of the current angle of rotation.

You also don't need `Timer` because both ObjectAnimator and rotateAnimator provide time control for you:

```js
rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000); // run animation for 1000 milliseconds or 1 second
rotateAnimation.setStartDelay(1000); // delay animation for 1000 milliseconds or 1 second
```

Finally, To get rotation Angle DURING the time animation is running there is a listener method called `addUpdateListener` :

```js
rotateAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    int value = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue(); // dynamic value of angle
  }
});
```

Comment: I have one more question, Is there a change frame rate of animation?
Because, onAnimationUpdate works when animation frame is update.
Because of this, even if you always rotate at the same angle(0->360), there is a slight difference, I can not give the event at a certain angle.

Comment: hey, No, there shouldn't be any rate change. Same animations should be animated the same. But, the view itself might cause some lags, that's all. maybe the image is too large. just try different time & values & I'm sure you will make them more smooth & natural-looking. also use "Interpolation" with them https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-interpolators-a-visual-guide