# Rotate Animation function,

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I was asked how to get the rotation angle in rotate animation.

[RotateAnimation Get Current angle of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007384/rotateanimation-get-current-angle-of-image?answertab=active#tab-top)

My final goal is to send the signal to the microcontroller according to the angle set by the running roulette.

I checked the log of the angle of the rotating image with the following code:

```
objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

                    double angle  = Double.parseDouble(objectAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());

                    Log.d("LOG", "animation : " + 

                }
                catch (Exception e){

                }

            }
        });

//setDuration -> 360
//range -> 0~360
//setInterpolator -> LinearInterpolator
```

The log is shown below.

```
D/LOG: animation : 0.0
D/LOG: animation : 0.0
D/LOG: animation : 33.0
D/LOG: animation : 49.0
D/LOG: animation : 66.0
D/LOG: animation : 83.0
D/LOG: animation : 99.0
D/LOG: animation : 133.0
D/LOG: animation : 150.0
D/LOG: animation : 166.0
D/LOG: animation : 183.0
D/LOG: animation : 216.00002
D/LOG: animation : 233.0
D/LOG: animation : 249.99998
D/LOG: animation : 266.0
D/LOG: animation : 283.0
D/LOG: animation : 316.0
D/LOG: animation : 333.0
D/LOG: animation : 350.0
D/LOG: animation : 360.0
```

I didn't give the image rotation any acceleration or deceleration with the LinearInterpolator setting.

I found that onAnimationUpdate called by animation frame rate.
(sure? not?)

I want to know the absolute angle, not the angle when it is animation updated.

How can I do?

and Is any other way to make a rotate animation and get absolute angle?

Thanks